# How to append data to div in ajax success in?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am new to jquery and frontend designing i am stuck with one problem, i am getting multidimensional array in ajax call i want to bind it to html div but i am unable to iterate loop in jquery function please tell solution thanks inadvance.Array which i am getting in ajax success is below

```
{
"parameter_id":"1",
"parameter_name":"PUC",
"parameter_datatype":"Date",
"parameter_code":"1",
"parameter_type":"Vehicle",
"parameter_setpoints":[
    {
        "setpoint_id":"1",
        "setpoint_code":"1",
        "setpoint_name":"Expiry Date",
        "setpoint_value_datatype":"Date",
        "action":null
    }
]},
```

and below is my jquery function

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url('test);?>",
      data:{'data_json':asset_type},
      success: function(data){

          var data =  JSON.stringify(data);
          $.each(data, function(key,value){
          $.each(data[key].parameter_setpoints, function(key2, value2){
              alert(data[key].parameter_setpoints[key2].setpoint_id);
          })
      })
   }
});
```

Comment: $('#your div id here').append or html(data[key].parameter_setpoints[key2].setpoint_id); or likes this syntax $(div).append(data);

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/stringify) converts an object/array into a JSON **string**, not an array.

You cannot iterate over a string to get your values.

You should use [`JSON.parse(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse) instead.

But jQuery could transform this for you by using `dataType: "json"`:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url('test);?>",
      data:{'data_json':asset_type},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data) ; 

          // Now, you can iterate over data.parameter_setpoints :
          for (var i = 0; i < data.parameter_setpoints.length; i++) {
             alert(data.parameter_setpoints[i].setpoint_id);
          }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your success method to below.

You might be receiving error because, you are first iterating an object. i.e., setpoint_id. In your scenario, if your parameter_setpoints is only an array. So as a fix, you can check if your key is parameter_setpoints and if its yes, iterate through it to get the needed setpoint_id.

```
      $.each(data, function(key,value){ // This is to iterate through your keys
      if(key == 'parameter_setpoints'){
      console.log(data[key])
      $.each(data[key], function(key2, value2){ //this is to iterate through your parameter_setpoints
          console.log(value2.setpoint_id)

      })
      }
  })
```

if you want to only iterate through your parameter_setpoints, you can directly use

```
$.each(data.parameter_setpoints, function(key2, value2){ this is to iterate through your parameter_setpoints
          console.log(value2.setpoint_id)
      })
```